# mke2fs says "Device or resource busy while setting up superblock"

Tags: filesystems, backup-restoration

I'm trying to test restoring a backed up linux file system /apps (ext3 filesystem)

```
/dev/cciss/c0d0p7     177G  3.8G  164G   3% /apps
```

I ran the following command to take a dump:

```
/sbin/dump -0uz -f /backup_labeir1/apps.dmp /apps
```

Then I deleted the /apps folder:

```
rm -rf /apps
```

And unmounted it:

```
umount -l /apps
```

Next I'm trying to make the file-system

```
mke2fs -j -b 4096 -L data /dev/cciss/c0d0p7
```

after which I'm planning to do the below steps:

```
# mkdir /apps
# mount -t ext3 /dev/cciss/c0d0p7 /apps
# cd /apps
# restore -rf /backup_labeir1/apps.dmp .
# reboot
```

I've 2 questions:

1. Are my testing steps correct
2. When I run the below I get the error:
   [root@labeir2 backup_labeir1]# mke2fs -F -j -b 4096 -L data       /dev/cciss/c0d0p7
   mke2fs 1.39 (29-May-2006)
   /dev/cciss/c0d0p7 is apparently in use by the system; mke2fs forced anyway.
   /dev/cciss/c0d0p7: Device or resource busy while setting up superblock

But neither the filesystem is mounted nor `lsof` shows me any output:

```
 lsof | grep /dev/cciss/c0d0p7
 lsof /dev/cciss/c0d0p7
```

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when I tried to format a USB drive on Mac OS X. In my case, unmounting the disk first with `diskutil unmountDisk ...` solved the problem.

Details: First, run `diskutil list` and check the output to figure out which disk you want to format. (Don't format your hard drive `disk0`!) In my case, it was `/dev/disk1`. When I first ran `mkfs.ext3 /dev/disk1`, I got the message "Resource busy while setting up superblock". But after I ran `diskutil unmountDisk disk1`, `mkfs.ext3` worked.

Note: Initially, I tried `diskutil eject disk1`, but then the disk is not accessible anymore - e.g. `diskutil list` doesn't show it. `diskutil unmountDisk disk1` makes sure that the disk is no longer in use, but `mkfs.ext3` can still access it.

Answer (score 0):

> /dev/cciss/c0d0p7: Device or resource busy while setting up superblock

From my experience, resource busy cause by multipath device map(might have). (e.g. /dev/mapper/mpathi)

If we have this problem, "mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/mpathi" and "" will fail.

```
[root@myserver ~]# multipath -ll mpathi
mpathi (snip:myFCdisk) dm-6 snip:myFCdiskProdName
size=100G features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=ro
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=snip:123 status=active
| `- 6:0:0:7  sdv  65:80  active ready  running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=snip:111 status=enabled
  `- 5:0:0:7  sdi  8:128  active ready  running
[root@myserver ~]#
[root@myserver ~]# mke2fs -F -t ext4 /dev/mapper/mpathi
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
/dev/mapper/mpathi: Operation not permitted while setting up superblock
[root@myserver ~]#
[root@myserver ~]# mke2fs -F -t ext4 /dev/sdv
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
/dev/sdv is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
[root@myserver ~]#
```

My workaround is removing multipath device map temporarily.

1. remove multipath device name.(multipath -f /dev/mapper/mpathi)
2. run mke2fs for mpath slave device(e.g. mke2fs -F -t ext4 /dev/sdv)
3. rebuild multipath device map.(multipath -r)

Have a good day:)